# Find sub-matrix containing the maximum number of elements consisting only of 1's

Tags: algorithm, matrix

A matrix of integers of size R x C (R rows, C columns) is given. All its elements have a value of 0 or 1. The rows of the matrix are numbered from 1 to R, the columns are numbered from 1 to C.

I am trying to find the most effective algorithm that will output r1, r2, c1, c2 of a sub matrix that consists only 1's and creates the maximum sum of those elements.

So far I thought of making a pre-matrix that counts the sum at each given element in the sub matrix (1, 1, r, c) and store it in a new matrix SUM (with same dimensions as the original matrix).

The formula for this could be then:

SUM[i, j] = SUM[i−1, j] + SUM[i, j−1] − SUM[i−1, i−1] + MATRIX[i, j]

If anyone has experience with a similar problem I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-rectangle-binary-sub-matrix-1s/amp/](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-size-rectangle-binary-sub-matrix-1s/amp/)?